# does a goroutine sending to an unbuffered channel without receivers block forever, after the function that spawns the goroutine returns?

Tags: go

please consider the following handler,

```golang
http.HandleFunc("/task", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", *cors)
        if r.Method != http.MethodPost {
            http.Error(w, "only POST method is allowed", http.StatusMethodNotAllowed)
            return
        }
        ack := make(chan bool)
        go func() {
            time.Sleep(time.Second)
            ack <- false
        }()
        server.BroadcastToRoom(r.FormValue("alias"), "task", task{TaskID: "1"}, func() {
            ack <- true
        })
        if a := <-ack; !a {
            w.WriteHeader(http.StatusNoContent)
        } else {
            w.WriteHeader(http.StatusCreated)
        }
    })
```

The `BroadcastToRoom` takes a callback as argument. In this callback (that might never happen) 
I send a boolean to the acknowledge channel. If not acknowledged after 1 second it times out.

I am experimenting with methods to implement the timeout. I wrote this goroutine and it works. 
However, according to [this playground](https://play.golang.org/p/Xusa-cwcZJ) a goroutine keeps running after the function that spawns it returns.

So I think because the goroutine keeps running and tries to send a value to an unbuffered channel without receivers, the goroutine will block forever. I could fix this by using a buffer size of 1, I guess.

I would like to know if my assumption is true. If so, is there a better way to stop it than using buffer size of 1 and let it silently finish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your scenario, the goroutine will leak (it will continue to exist). The proper way of terminating the goroutine if nobody is listening to that channel is to use a nonblocking write:

```
 go func() {
            time.Sleep(time.Second)
            select {
               case ack <- false:
               default:
            }
        }()
```

This way, if nobody was listening after the timeout, it'll select the `default`, and terminate the goroutine.

Comment: thank you. Do you think this is a good way to implement a timeout here?

Comment: No. Take a look at context.WithTimeout. Also take a look at time.Tick.

Comment: Ok thanks, I was looking at context.  The examples always define a function that takes this as argument though. I was experimenting with passing it to the goroutine. Anyway, thanks for the hint. I will look into these 2 things.

Comment: Tick might work better for you. There is context in http.Request. Also, you can create a context and pass it to a lenghty computation as well.

Comment: I ended up using context, here is the snippet if you/someone is interested. I am happy with that.  https://play.golang.org/p/GY9UFYwVQgg